# 800A004C Path not found

Tags: vbscript

My file is in the correct folder and the error even gives me the correct path name so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

```
Next

Dim objShell
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "hidden\host.vbs" 
Set objShell = Nothing
```

I have even tried passing the value in a variable, using the full path, and different shell methods still the same result.

Comment: Is your working directory what you think it is? (`WScript.Echo objShell.CurrentDirectory`)

Comment: I can confirm that my current directory is correct using the Echo command. The error message states that "C:\hidden\host.vbs" is missing which is weird because I can see the file and I copied the name directly from file properties to avoid typos

Comment: Wild guess: hidden file extension? What does `dir C:\hidden` in a Command Prompt show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`800A004C Path not found` error message](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_800A004C.htm) does not come from shown code snippet.

**It comes from `"hidden\host.vbs"` script**.

> *Troubleshooting Code 800A004C - Path not found*
>
> For once error 800A004C is not the VBScript's fault.  Check the name
>   of the file and or folder referenced in the script.
>
> *Introduction to Error 800A004C*
>  Error 800A004C occurs when you execute a VBScript.  My suggestion is that you are trying to read, or
>   write, to a file reference that does not exist.  A wild guess, there
>   is a typo in your Path statement.Code 800A004C Error - Path not found.
>   VBScript Microsoft
>
> *The Symptoms You Get 800A004C*
>  When you get a WSH pop-up message box.  Put on your detective hat and pay close attention to the line
>   number.  Error 800A004C is a runtime error, so the problem is likely
>   to outside your script, there could be something the matter with a
>   file location.
>
> [image: 800A004C]
>
> *The Cause of Error 800A004C*
>  In the example above, Line 12: is the source of the error.  Char 1: is not always very useful as the
>   error could be anywhere on the line and char 1 will be blamed by WSH.
>   (Windows Script Host)
>
> The cause of error 800A004C is likely to be that the folder that you
>   wish to create the file does not exist.  The VBScript is capable of
>   creating the file, but there is no such directory.

Error raised from `objShell.Run "hidden\host.vbs"` would be `80070002` if target file (command) does not exist.

[image: 80070002]

Comment: Thanks, I will be raising another question my script now works but when I try to run it from a scheduled task I get the the 8007002 error on a separate ticket.